# PostgreSQL: could not translate host name: <address> to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean

I am trying to migrate postgre db from DO VM into DO's PostgreSQL managed database.

I used `pg_dump` for specific database, and use `pg_restore` to load the data.

All went well, except until I turn off the old VM, querying the data from new managed database lead to

```
could not translate host name: <address> to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Whereas if querying from the VM that I've turned off, lead to expected result,

```
could not connect to server: Connection timed out
```

Confusingly, if I turn back on the VM, the managed database works without any issue.

I'm using command below to dump database,

```
pg_dump -h <> -U <> -p <> -Fc <> > <>.bak
```

And to restore,

```
psql -d  <connection-string> -f <>.bak
```

Is it a firewall issue, or have I misunderstood something about DO's managed database?

I read https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/databases/postgresql/resources/troubleshoot-connections/#could-not-translate-hostname-to-address, the hostname is no issue since I can pull data if the VM is on.

Answer (score -3):

After doing research `Temporary failure in name resolution` is a common issue for incorrect config in DNS, and fix it by looking at `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What did you actually do with  /etc/resolv.conf file?

Comment: This really couldn't be a more unhelpful answer. Can you say what you actually did to fix it?